# Submitting the form manually using Ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am trying to call a servlet on form submit using ajax. But it's not hitting the ajax and page reloads. I am triggering form submit manually and after that on that submit function i am calling the ajax method.

```js
$("#image1").on('change', function(event) {
  $('#myform').trigger('submit');
  alert("button clicked"); // this is submitted

  $("#myform").submit(function(e) { // this is not happening
    event.preventDefault();

    alert('form clicked');
    //var formId=("#myform").submit();
    $.ajax({
      type: 'GET', // GET or POST or PUT or DELETE
      // verb
      url: "/bin/mr/controller?q=iechange",
      data: $("#myform").serialize(),
      // type
      // sent
      // to
      // server
      dataType: 'json', // Expected data format from
      // server
      processdata: true, // True or False
      success: function(data) { // On Successfull

        alert('call success');
        console.log(data);



      },
      error: function(msg) { // When Service call
        alert('call fail'); // fails

      }
    });



  });


});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="myform" >
<input name="img" id="image1" type="file" accept="image/*">
</form>
```

Comment: I assume you want to use a `POST` for submitting a form. Also, you're passing `e` as the `event` param - but then trying to use `event.preventDefault()` - should be `e.preventDefault()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to bind your `submit` event handler when the page loads.

Currently you are trying to bind it after you have manually triggered the submission… which is too late because the event will have been and gone by then.

Move the code which binds the `submit` event **outside** the event handler for the `change` event.